# Why should the "key" part in a JS hash/dict be a string?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, coding-style

In most JSON serializers/deserializers, the "key" part in a javascript dictionary/hash array is written as a string.

What is the benefit of using a string as the key as opposed to just typing the intended name in?

For example, say I define two objects `k1` and `k2` like so:

```
var k1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };          // define name normally
var k2 = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 };    // define name with a string
```

And I then ran the following tests:

```
alert(k1 == k2);                   // false (of course)

alert(k1.a == k2.a);               // true
alert(k1["b"] == k2["b"]);         // true

alert(uneval(k1));                 // returns the k1 object literal notation.
alert(uneval(k2));                 // returns the same string as above line.

alert(uneval(k1) == uneval(k2));   // true
```

So what's the point of having the keys be in double-quotation marks (a string) as in the way `k2` was defined instead of just typing the key names in as in the way `k1` was defined?

---

I just saw this over at [Ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/archives/chrome-extension-api-how-we-wish-we-have-named-parameters) pointing to [Aaron Boodman's blog entry](http://www.aaronboodman.com/2009/04/yo-dawg.html):

```
chromium.tabs.createTab({
 "url": "http://www.google.com/",
 "selected": true,
 "tabIndex": 3
});
```

Since he also use camel case for tabIndex, I don't see any point in using a string at all.

Why not:

```
chromium.tabs.createTab({
 url: "http://www.google.com/",
 selected: true,
 tabIndex: 3
});
```

Why would a JS ninja follows the convention of turning `url`, `selected` and `tabIndex` into a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is a subset of the actual JavaScript literal syntax. For simplicity in implementing JSON parsers, double quotes are always required around strings, and as keys in JSON are strings, they are required there.

Not all legal JavaScript is legal JSON. While you can define object literals in JavaScript without the quotes, if you want interoperable JSON, you're going to need to put them in.

Comment: I suppose the convention in javascript just were leaked over from having working with a lot of JSON then...

Comment: I believe python compatibility was mentioned as a reason for quotes

Comment: @chakrit Yes. Also, as pointed out by gizmo, it's generally safer to use quotes in JavaScript since you don't have to worry about reserved words. For instance {do: "something"} is not legal JavaScript.

Comment: Actually “{do: "something"}” does work! Obviously there are other characters and string that can confuse that syntax, though, so you're *sometimes* going to need the quotes, and if you need it sometimes them could be easiest to just always include them.

Comment: @bobince Oops, you're right. When I was testing it, I made another mistake in my syntax, and the error threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

Because doing so, you avoid to use, by error, a javascript reserved keyword, like "do" for example. Using the string notation kept you on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

If the syntax diagram at json.org is to be believed, bareword property names are nonstandard.  How many browsers did you run your tests on?

Comment: Not much... but I *do* maintain a huge javascript application at work. And I use the bareword names all the time (e.g. creating class and such) and it works in all major browsers... IE FF Opera Safari.

Comment: JSON is a subset of JavaScript. It requires quotes, but JavaScript doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from getting away from reserved keywords you can actually use whatever characters in your property names - including spaces, colons...

Not really sure why would you do that. I prefer using the normal "object" notation.